# regex in python to remove 2 patterns

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Want to make a regex to remove 2019 and 0 from left side of the string and last six zeroes from right side of the string.

```
original value Dtype :  class 'str'
original value:  2019 01 10 00 00 00   

expected output is : 1 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.split` with list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
s = "2019 01 10 00 00 00"
print(" ".join(s.split()[1:3]).lstrip("0"))
```

---

Using `re.match`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "2019 01 10 00 00 00"

m = re.match(r"\d{4}\b\s(?P<value>\d{2}\b\s\d{2}\b)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group("value").lstrip("0"))
```

**Output:**

```
1 10
```